# How to search an element in column of a dataframe containing lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `df` which contains two columns. First column `sentence` contains the sentence and second column `keywords` contains the all the keywords in list from the sentence in the first column. So my dataframe looks something like this :

```
>>> df
                                       sentence                          keywords
0        What are the advantages of the prepaid             [advantages, prepaid]
1     is salon facility available in your hotel          [salon, facility, hotel]
2  I want to check my balance and usage history  [check, balance, usage, history]
```

Now suppose I have a `list` like `["salon", "usage", "history"]` containing the keywords which I want to search against the `keywords` column and in return I want to get all the sentences containing the keywords in the given list. So the output in this particular case would be :

```
>>> output
["is salon facility available in your hotel", "I want to check my balance and usage history"]
```

What is the fastest and most efficient way of achieving this result because I have thousands of sentences in the `sentence` column. The only way I know to achieve this to get all the lists from `keywords` column in a separate list and enumerate over it and get the indexes of the all the sub-lists containing the keywords and then look for same indexes in the `sentence` column. But this would be very slow. Is there any other better way of doing this?

Data:

```
data = {'sentence': ['What are the advantages of the prepaid',
                     'is salon facility available in your hotel',
                     'I want to check my balance and usage history'],
        'keywords': [['advantages', 'prepaid'],
                     ['salon', 'facility', 'hotel'],
                     ['check', 'balance', 'usage', 'history']]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set.isjdisoint` and check if there are any overlapping words with the "keywords" to create a boolean mask. Then, use the mask on `df` to filter the matching sentences:

```
lst = ["salon", "usage", "history"]
msk = df['keywords'].apply(lambda x: not set(x).isdisjoint(lst))
out = df.loc[msk, 'sentence'].tolist()
```

Output:

```
['is salon facility available in your hotel', 'I want to check my balance and usage history']
```

Answer (score 1):

For each row you should check the set intersection (or difference) to determine which sentences' keywords overlap with the search keywords:

```py
search_words = {'salon', 'usage', 'history'}

def search(keywords, search_words):
  return not search_words.isdisjoint(keywords)

results = df['keywords'].apply(search, args=(search_words,))

df.loc[results, 'sentence'].tolist()
```